# Same Apache Spark query, Different Execution Plan on local/EMR Spark vs Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

While trying the execution plan of a query, Apache Spark behaves differently on local/EMR vs Databricks.

I have tried this for Apache Spark 2.3.2 and 2.4.2 on local/EMR, and Spark 2.4.0 on Databricks.

Consider the following code

```scala
val squared = (s: Long) => {
  println("squared called")
  s * s
}
val squared_udf = spark.udf.register("square", squared)
spark.range(1).withColumn("a",squared_udf(lit(5))).withColumn("b",expr("a+5")).withColumn("v",lit(7)).explain
```

When this executes on Apache Spark on Local machine or AWS EMR, the output is as

```sh
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [id#0L, UDF:square(id#0L) AS s#10L, (cast(UDF:square(id#0L) as double) / 2.0) AS half#13]
+- *(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=8)
```

But in the case of Databricks, the output as:

```sh
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [id#251L, a#253L, (a#253L + 5) AS b#256L, 7 AS v#260]
+- *(1) Project [id#251L, UDF:square(5) AS a#253L]
   +- *(1) Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=8)
```

Why there is a difference in the output? Is there any Spark configuration for this, or does Databricks has its own custom version on top of Apache Spark?
The execution plan on local/EMR executes the UDF twice, which could result in performance problems. But the execution plan on Databricks has somehow handled it.

Comment: Different codes bases?

Comment: I tried this multiple times, use the exact same code, but the behaviour is different.

Comment: Very odd, do you get correct result on the odd plan?

Comment: In both cases, the final DataFrame is same, but the UDF execution count changes. In the case of Databricks UDF is called 1 time for each row, final in another case, it is called 2 times for each row. I have also tried to have a println statement in UDF, this also proved the point.